# R: How do I select certain column names alphabetically but have some exceptions?

Tags: r

I'm trying to find a way to pull out certain column names from different dataframes where I want to favor alphabetical sorting but have at least one exception. For my example (see below!) - I want to sort colname alphabetically within each category *except for Temp_A and Temp_C* (*or a variation of each, such as Temp_A_1 or Temp_C_2*), where I want to select Temp_C before Temp_A. At the same time, I want to prefer numbers before letters (*ex. Temp1 should come before TempA*).

- **dataset1 columns: Temp4, Temp2, TempA, TempC, PA, PB, and
  PC**

---> Desired output: **Temp2 and PC**

- **dataset2 columns: P_A_1 , P_1_2 , P_C_3 , Temp_C_6 , Temp_A_7 , and

  Temp_B_3**

---> Desired output: **P_1_2 and Temp_C_6**

**Note: The dataset includes names like Petal.Length and Petal.Width which we want to ignore when selecting the P* variables (this is on purpose as my actual dataset has other variables starting with P that I want to ignore)**

*This question is a build on the question listed here: [R: How do I rename columns based on ranked conditions for the purpose of compiling data from multiple sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75699958/r-how-do-i-rename-columns-based-on-ranked-conditions-for-the-purpose-of-compili/75700100?noredirect=1#comment133623997_75700100)*
*Thank you Jon Spring for your help with this!*

Example datasets:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

dataset1 <- as_tibble(iris)
dataset2 <- as_tibble(iris)

dataset1$Temp4 <- sample(50, size = nrow(dataset1), replace = TRUE)
dataset1$Temp2 <- sample(50, size = nrow(dataset1), replace = TRUE)
dataset1$TempA <- sample(50, size = nrow(dataset1), replace = TRUE)
dataset1$TempC <- sample(50, size = nrow(dataset1), replace = TRUE)

dataset1$PA <- sample(50, size = nrow(dataset1), replace = TRUE)
dataset1$PB <- sample(50, size = nrow(dataset1), replace = TRUE)
dataset1$PC <- sample(50, size = nrow(dataset1), replace = TRUE)

dataset2$P_A_1 <- sample(50, size = nrow(dataset2), replace = TRUE)
dataset2$P_1_2 <- sample(50, size = nrow(dataset2), replace = TRUE)
dataset2$P_C_3 <- sample(50, size = nrow(dataset2), replace = TRUE)

dataset2$Temp_C_6 <- sample(50, size = nrow(dataset2), replace = TRUE)
dataset2$Temp_A_7 <- sample(50, size = nrow(dataset2), replace = TRUE)
dataset2$Temp_B_3 <- sample(50, size = nrow(dataset2), replace = TRUE)
```

Comment: The current phrasing of this question seems 10x more complicated than it needs to be, since the only additive piece from the prior question is "Given a variable with column names and a variable with categories for them, how do I apply a different sorting method [for example...] depending on the category?"  It will be easier for people to help if you just ask for one specific programming question at a time, rather than making it into a consulting project.

Comment: Agreed -  not the best phrasing. I am looking to sort column names tho, not categories? tho, i think i might have fixed it. Thank you :)

Comment: What I meant is you have a few paragraphs of explanation and 40+ lines of code, when I think your specific question here could be simplified by providing a data frame with one variable listing some column names, and another variable with categories you've assigned (let's assume you've figured that out separately). You have 2 or three sorting methodologies, and you want certain categories to use one, others to use another. You could add a third variable to show the desired ordering within each category, so people could easily confirm if they are interpreting your description right.

Comment: I think I fixed it? I'm not sure if the method would be the same if the column names were inside a column?